# IInputArray image parameter for face detection in emgucv in c# using haarcascade

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I have installed **emgu.cv 3.2 (new version)** and **visual studio 2012** and for the face detection using windows form application I tried to used haarcascade. I have done the referencing

> (Emgu.CV.DebuggerVisualizers.VS2012.dll, Emgu.CV.UI.dll,
>   Emgu.CV.UI.GL.dll, Emgu.CV.World.dll)

and add existing

> (opencv_ffmpeg320.dll and others)

. The new version of **emgu.cv** seems to have changed some names of methods like Capture replaced by VideoCapture. But still, I am stuck to complete the face detection code below (last code). What should I do to put IInputArray image parameter on DetectMultiScale(). Please help!

```
    capture = new VideoCapture(0);
    haar = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>()
    Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
     // stuck here below to put IInputArray image    
                        var faces = haar.DetectMultiScale( , 1.1, 10, 
                          Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HaarDetectionType.DoCannyPruning,  
                          new Size(20, 20));
      // or you can use this to code
                        MCvAvgComp[][] faces = 
                      haar.DetectMultiScale(**IInputArray image** , 1.1, 
                      10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HaarDetectionType.DoCannyPruning, 
                      new Size(20, 20));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new EmguCv uses Mat as the image format by default. so in the IInputArray you need to pass the Mat

```
Mat matFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = matFrame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()
Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();

var faces = haar.DetectMultiScale( matFrame, 1.1, 10, 
                  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HaarDetectionType.DoCannyPruning,  
                  new Size(20, 20));
```

**IInputArray and IOutArray are interfaces which accept:**

- A CvArray, which is the base class of Matrix and Image<,>
- A Mat, which is the Open CV equivalent of cv::Mat
- A UMat, which is the Open CV equivalent of cv::UMat
- A ScalarArray, which can be used to convert a scalar to an IInputArray
- VectorOf{XXX}, this is the interface for the C++ standard vector

Comment: I was trying to use face detection from emgu cv tutorial: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection but now that "Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HaarDetectionType.DoCannyPruning" is throwing error.

Comment: Inside the DetectMultiScale, i could not use "Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HaarDetectionType.DoCannyPrunning" parameter. How to do CannyPrunning then?

Comment: I am lost in this CannyPrunning in that same function? So couldn't go anywhere there. But you are right that we can directly use image format of emgu cv directly in that function.